# Tax on Sale of Property

Tags: taxes, india, real-estate, capital-gain

My uncle has sold his property and he deposited the money he received from selling the property. I like to know, if he keeps that amount in his bank account for an year, will that money be taxed? He is a senior citizen and has no income. Should the money be invested to avoid any tax deduction?

Answer (score 1):

You uncle is liable to pay "Capital-Gains" tax. Essentially the sale price less of cost would be treated as gains. The gains are taxed at 10% without indexation and 20% with Indexation.

The capital gains tax can be avoided if your uncle invests the gains into specified "Infrastructure bonds" or buys another property within a period of 3 years. The funds need to be kept in a separate "Capital Gains" account and not a regular savings account till you buy another property within 3 years.