# In which infrastructure bonds should one invest to avoid capital gains tax after selling a property in India?

Tags: income-tax, india, real-estate, capital-gain, property-taxes

This is a follow-up question to 
[Taxes on sale of property](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/49558/tax-on-sale-of-property)

1. What are the available infrastructure bonds and can one withdraw that amount at any moment or some lock-in period is there?
2. How capital gain account is different from savings account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the available infrastructure bonds

The available bonds keep changing. This can't be answered as its a product recommendation. Ask your broker or Bank or watch the newspapers, you will know what is currently available. At times there maybe no bond available.

> and can one withdraw that amount at any moment or some lock-in period is there?

Yes generally a lock-in period of 3 years.

> How capital gain account is different from savings account?

A capital gains account is a Bank Account. The deposit in this only allowed upon submitting the documents verifying that the money is due to capital gains. Withdrawal is only permitted to buy another property, else tax has to be paid at withdrawal. Talk to your banker and he should be able to explain more details.